# How to fetch message embeds with the message id discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am working on an advanced suggestion command and here's my code so far:

```
if (command === 'accept') {
 try {
  const suggestionchan = bot.channels.cache.get('840493081659834403');
  const acceptreason = message.content.split(' ')[2];
  if(!acceptreason) return message.lineReply("Please provide the reason!")
  const messageid = message.content.split(' ')[1];
  console.log(messageid)
  if(!messageid) return message.lineReply("Please provide the message id of the suggestion!")
  const suggestionData = suggestionchan.messages.fetch(messageid)
  const suggestionembed = suggestionData.embeds[0];
  const acceptembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setAuthor(suggestionembed.author.name, suggestionembed.author.iconURL)
  .setTitle("Suggestion!")
  .setDescription(suggestionembed.description)
  .setColor("GREEN")
  .addFields(
    { name: `Accepted by ${message.author.tag}`, value: `**Reason:**\n${acceptreason}`}
  )
  .setFooter("Bot made by Sɱαɾƚx Gαɱιɳɠ YT")
  suggestionembed.edit(acceptembed)
  message.delete();
  const user = bot.users.cache.find( (u) => u.tag === suggestionembed.author.name);
  user.send(acceptembed)
} catch (err) { console.log(err)
  message.lineReply("That message ID is not a valid ID!")}
}
```

I am getting an error on the part `suggestionembed = suggestionData.embeds[0];`

The error is `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined at Client.<anonymous>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`suggestionchan.messages.fetch`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageManager?scrollTo=fetch) returns a promise, so you'll need to resolve it first. You can either use the `.then()` method or the `await` keyword (as below).

It's also a good idea to check if the fetched message have any embeds.

```js
if (command === 'accept') {
  try {
    const suggestionChannel = bot.channels.cache.get('840493081659834403');
    const acceptReason = message.content.split(' ')[2];
    if (!acceptReason)
      return message.lineReply('Please provide the reason!');

    const messageId = message.content.split(' ')[1];
    if (!messageId)
      return message.lineReply('Please provide the message id of the suggestion!');

    const suggestionData = await suggestionChannel.messages.fetch(messageId);
    const suggestionEmbed = suggestionData.embeds[0];
    if (!suggestionEmbed)
      return message.lineReply(`The message with ID ${messageId} doesn't have any embeds!`);

    const acceptEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setAuthor(suggestionEmbed.author.name, suggestionEmbed.author.iconURL)
      .setTitle('Suggestion!')
      .setDescription(suggestionEmbed.description)
      .setColor('GREEN')
      .addFields({
        name: `Accepted by ${message.author.tag}`,
        value: `**Reason:**\n${acceptReason}`,
      })
      .setFooter('Bot made by Sɱαɾƚx Gαɱιɳɠ YT');
    suggestionData.edit(acceptEmbed);
    message.delete();

    const user = bot.users.cache.find(
      (u) => u.tag === suggestionEmbed.author.name,
    );
    user.send(acceptEmbed);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    message.lineReply('That message ID is not a valid ID!');
  }
}
```

Comment: But now it's throwing a new error `suggestionEmbed.edit is not a function` please help

Comment: Oh, you can't edit an embed, but a message. It should be `suggestionData.edit(acceptEmbed)`.

Comment: Thank you soo much for helping me i will never forgot about you :')